# "The most rude" or "the rudest"?

Tags: superlatives, comparative

[Rude *comparative* ruder *superlative* rudest](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rude)

But **the most rude** is applied in the following title:

[The Most Rude, ill-Mannered, and Humiliating Plays in NBA History!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-go6B_OxpoY)

Can we use both forms for any circumstance?

Comment: The general "rule" applied to superlatives is if it only has one syllable - or two and ends in a vowel sound; as, "angry" - then you would use the word plus it's superlative ending. Otherwise, one would use "most [word]." However this isn't set in stone and either form can be used as needed.

Comment: The word "ruder" e.g. is just fine, and probably more frequently used. What sounds better will depend on context. 

'He is ruder than anyone I ever met.' Normal

'He is more rude than anyone I ever met.' (Correct but not as natural as the first.)

'He couldn't be more rude.' (Normal.)

'He couldn't be ruder.' (Normal, but the first version is a bit more natural.)

Answer (score 17):

> The Most Rude, ill-Mannered, and Humiliating Plays in NBA History!

If we use **rudest** here, we would have to still use "most" for the other adjectives:

> The Rudest, Most ill-Mannered, and Most Humiliating Plays in NBA History!

The title uses "most" to apply to all three adjectives, because "ill-Manneredest" is a word I've never seen nor would wish to see in a title, unless written in jest, and there's no "humiliatingest".

Hence, the most logical, or logicalest, way is just to attach "most" at the start of the title.

Comment: Is *logicalest* a superlative?

Comment: @Ustanak - there is no such word in common usage, I made it up for humor's sake.

Comment: Thought you meant it, that's why you got my curiosity arisen.

Comment: I think that the version with *rudest* would have to be "the rudest, most ill-mannered, and most humiliating", since otherwise the "most" only seems to have scope over "ill-mannered" rather than over "ill-mannered and humiliating".

Answer (score 2):

You know, I often wonder, as I stare at our recycling bin:

[image: No hot ashes]

Is *cold* liquid acceptable?

This ambiguity could easily have been resolved by printing `NO LIQUID OR HOT ASHES`.

In the example from the question, it could be reworded as:

"The Most ill-Mannered, Humiliating and Rudest Plays in NBA History!"

Comment: No.  Because hot liquid will quickly turn into outside-temperature liquid, assuming the dumpster is outside and there are no other forces causing the temperature to differ.  Unless liquid is so hot that it melts the dumpster, there is no reason why they would care about only hot liquids.  Hence, the message must just be referring to liquid in general.  So the obvious lesson, to be learned here, is to make sure that zero percent of your garbage can pass through a strainer before it is thrown away.

Comment: Although I think there is nothing wrong with 'most rude' in the first place, so no rewording seems necessary! And probably the writer put 'rude' at the beginning to make sure nobody would take 'rude' as a simple adjective and not a superlative. He simply tried to emphasize on his choice of structure which is defendable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, ***yes you can use [RUDE](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/rude)*** (it's a link) in both forms, i.e. *rudest* and *most rude*. There are some adjectives that can be used in both forms such as *rude, clever, friendly, sure, crazy, likely, simple, common*.

Apart from what you can find in dictionaries sometimes it gets tricky when people simply use a form that they think is easier or more beautiful to articulate.

As CowperKettle well pointed out, *most* has been elided afterwards to avoid repetition. There is no problem with using *most rude* in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Ya I too think it totally depends on the context and how natural you want to sound.

**rude**

**ruder** or **more rude**

**rudest** or **most rude**

In some context rudest may be good and sound natural while in other most rude may be more natural. It's up to you what you want to use.